# Recursive formula of a sequence containing a function

Tags: python, recursion, sequence

I am to write a recursive sequence and print it's n first values.
There are the functions coded:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2 - 4

def h(x):
    return (x-(((3-x)*f(x))/(f(3)-f(x))))
```

and now I would like to code the recursive sequence and print n first values of it:

*x<sub>n+1</sub> = h(x<sub>n</sub>)*

For x<sub>1</sub> = 4/3

My code isn't working of course (I receive the same value n times but I would like to get something alike):

```
def g(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        x = 4/3
        x = h(x)
        print(x)
```

Comment: P. S.  
Why LateX isn't working on StackOverflow?

Comment: You should assign x=4/3 before the loop. Now it becomes 4/3 with every iteration.

Comment: @Hendrra http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Hendrra Regarding the lack of LaTeX on Stack Overflow, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on. Apparently, supporting LaTeX slows down page loads even on pages that don't use LaTeX, and that is most pages here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both for the link and the solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply overwrite `x` with `4/3` each iteration:

```
def g(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        x = 4/3
        x = h(x)
        print(x)
```

Simply move the statement above the loop:

```
def g(n):
    x = 4/3
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        x = h(x)
        print(x)
```

Perhaps you also want to `print(x)` before you enter the loop.

Nevertheless, you can improve your code on some points: first of all I would not `print` the result: printing has side-effects. In a program you usually try to make a distinction between functions that calculate and functions that have side-effects.

Next and in the same context, I would use a [**generator**](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) an not return a list or something. You can simply define the sequence for an arbitrary amount of indices:

```
def g():
    x = 4/3
    while True:
        x = h(x)
        yield x
```

Now you can ask `g` for for instance the first 10 elements, or perform filters, ... Elements are furthermore generated lazily.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't known about the generators which and as I can see they might be useful.